# Why is the normalisation of a singular curve never flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

In Vakil's notes on Algebraic Geometry, he states in exercise 24.4.H that the normalisation of a singular curve is never flat and he claims that this is a simple consequence of the fact that every finite morphism $f:X\to Y$ is flat iff $f_*O_X$ is locally free.

Now I was thinking as follows. Denote the singular point of $Y$ by $y$. Then, $Y\setminus y\cong X\setminus f^{-1}(y)$, so $f$ is flat away from the point $y$, since isomorphisms are flat by definition.
Thus consider $g=f\mid_{f^{-1}(y)}:f^{-1}(y)\to y$. $g$ is finite, thus to not be a flat map, we need to see that $g_*O_{f^{-1}(y)}$ is not locally free. Consider $$0\to O_y\to g_*O_{f^{-1}(y)}\to coker(g^*)\to 0.$$ If we are given $\phi\in O_y$, i.e. $\phi:U=U(y)\to k$, then $g^*\phi:g^{-1}(U)\to k$ gives an element of $g_*O_{f^{-1}(y)}$ and a map $g^{-1}(U)\to k$ is determined by its values on $g^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y)$ which consists of either one or two points, depending on whether we are given a node or not. The cokernel thus is a skyscraper sheaf supported at $y$, if we are dealing with a cusp, and trivial otherwise. In both situations, it seems that $g_*O_{f^{-1}(y)}$ is a free $O_y$-module of finite rank which would imply that $f$ is flat.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check the dimension too!  You have: The stalk of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ at $y$ is of a different rank than the stalk at other points, so $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is not locally free.

Comment: @user10354138 OK, I see this for singularities which are not unibranch ($|f^{-1}(y)|\geq 2$) but is we have unibranch singularities, e.g. the cusp, then it seems that $g_*O_{f^{-1}(y)}$ has rank one over $y$ and thus everywhere. Could you add more explanation in this case?

Comment: If you try to do the computation, e.g., $(t^2,t^3)$, you see you are missing the $t$ in $k[t^2,t^3]\to k[t]$ before you take stalks (localize if you want, it is still missing), so actually has a cokernel.

Comment: So what does the cokernel then tell us geometrically in this case? Is there a way to see that we have a cokernel in general, showing that normalization of singular curves is not flat in the general case?

Comment: The stalk carries infinitesimal information, and it is the first-order expansion that a cusp cannot reproduce.

Comment: Would you mind to write an actual proof as an answer? I understand this kind of things geometrically, but I can't write down a proof showing that, regardless of the singularity, it is never flat.

Comment: @user650973 This follows (not only for curves) from Exercise 7.2 in Matsumura, which asserts that: if $A \subset B$ is a faithfully flat inclusion of integral domains having the same fraction field, then $A=B$.